# Android: bitmap size exceeds VM budget. Loading images into a canvas

Tags: android, android-ndk, drawable, android-canvas, out-of-memory

I tried to find solutions in other questions like mine but couldn't find anything.

I am loading a bunch of images into a canvas. However, I am getting a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget. I am using a real phone for testing (Nexus One). The app crashes. It works fine on my Samsung Vibrate.

Here's my code:

CustomDrawableView.java

```
package com.images.testimage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
private Drawable canada;
private Drawable usa;
private Drawable mexico;

public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
    super(context);


    Resources res = context.getResources();
    canada = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.canada);
    canada.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + canada.getMinimumWidth(), 0 + canada.getMinimumHeight());

    usa = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.usa);
    usa.setBounds(0,0,usa.getMinimumWidth(),
            usa.getMinimumHeight());

    mexico = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.mexico);
    mexico.setBounds(0,0,mexico.getMinimumWidth(),
            mexico.getMinimumHeight());
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canada.draw(canvas);
    usa.draw(canvas);
    mexico.draw(canvas);
}
}
```

canada, usa and mexico are pngs. Each is 5kb.

Here's the main code:

TestImageActivity.java

```
package com.images.testimage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class TestImagesActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);
    setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);
    setRequestedOrientation(0);

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

It works on my Nexus One when I only load 2 images like usa and canada. Not with 3. I am suppose to load like 20 more countries like those. Help please?

Here's a sample canada.png image... Its white coloured.. if you highlight and drag it, you will see the image...

[image]

Comment: -1 ... This question is asked 5 times in a week ...

Comment: -1 Agreed with selvin.u never check on SO.

Comment: Double Agreed.  This is how easy a search is:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Android+bitmap+size+exceeds+VM+budget   This returns about 5000 results

Comment: Your image is quite large with mostly blank space. How about create new images without all of the wasted space?

Comment: Yes folks might be a dupe, but a dupe of what? How about using that flagging button up there and doing something constructive rather than bumping gums about how "dupe" it is. :/

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution is reduce image resolution. Unfortunately there is no other good work around.